# "Unexpected token else" inside $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, syntax-error, each

For some reason, I'm getting an `Unexpected token else` error for this script:

```
.each(rowValue.columns, function(columnKey, columnValue){
    if(typeof rowValue.type !== 'undefined' && rowValue.type == 'header'){
        $(this).append(
            $('<div></div>').prop('name', columnValue.name).text(columnValue.text).addClass('orangeStatusTwoThirdsCell blueCellOverride').applyHTMLclasses(columnValue.classes);
        );
    }
    else if(columnValue.inputType == 'textarea'){
        $(this).append(
            $('<textarea></textarea>').prop('rows', columnValue.textareaRows).prop('id', columnValue.id).addClass('fillContainer inputAsCell hideScrollbar').applyHTMLclasses(columnValue.classes);
        );
    }
    else if(columnValue.inputType == 'select'){
        $(this).append(
            $('<select></select>').prop('id', columnValue.id).addClass('fillContainer inputAsCell').applyHTMLclasses(columnValue.classes).append(function(){
                if(typeof columnValue.valuelessSelectOption !== 'undefined'){$(this).append($('<option/>').text(columnValue.valuelessSelectOption));}
            });
        );
    }
});
```

I'm `$.append()`ing these to dynamically constructed elements.

Comment: You have other errors.

Comment: @dystroy do you mind showing me?  tia!

Comment: Is it a typo or you forgot `$` before `.each()`?

Comment: A code with shorter lines is often easier to parse by humans. The line starting with `if(typeof columnValu` is especially hard to read. I won't check it as I hate to have to use an horizontal scrollbar repetitively.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon there's a lot more before that.  just included the relevant parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ; at the end of the middle line in this :

```
if(typeof rowValue.type !== 'undefined' && rowValue.type == 'header'){
    $(this).append(
        $('<div></div>').prop('name', columnValue.name).text(columnValue.text).addClass('orangeStatusTwoThirdsCell blueCellOverride').applyHTMLclasses(columnValue.classes);
    );
}
```

You have the same problem a few lines after.

Comment: This `;` is changing the expression into a statement, which can't be an argument of the append function.